# My son and I share my phone. Well I can not access my account through google as it automatically signs him back in

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm trying to access my account, but it will not give any options to switch accounts on Google. It just automatically signs my son in.

Comment: Many of these free, online-only mobile games rely on building a user profile that they can sell to advertisers to support the game's development.  The phone's advertising device id (assigned in the OS) is commonly used as a unique identifier of the person this profile represents.  Allowing two people to maintain separate accounts on a single phone would conflate the behaviours of both people into one "user profile," which in turn makes that profile less valuable to advertisers.  This is why the game devs usually make it difficult (if not impossible) to switch accounts on a single device.

Comment: Have you added both Google accounts to the device?

Answer (score 1):

Try starting up the Pokemon Go ap while on Flight modus. After a short while there will be a button that you can change/sign in with another account. Ofcourse, don't forget to shut the flight mode off after that.

Answer (score 0):

Let Pokémon GO auto-login to your son's account, then go to `menu > settings > sign out`. You will be prompted to login with a gmail / trainer account right afterwards.

If you, for some reason, can't login to your sons account fully close Pokémon GO and restart it. Once you see the first loading bar turn on flight mode until you see a Logout-Button in the top-right, then login with your account.